# Passing a list variable from javascript to HTML Email in GAS

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, html-email

Thanks everyone for input on this. Here's the code:

```
var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
    var subject = header + " Team";
    var body = "";
    var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('daily-email');
    htmlTemplate.mgrname = "Test1";
    htmlTemplate.tmname = "Test2";
    htmlTemplate.mDayUpdate = '<table><tr><th>Result</th><th>Points</th></tr>' + 
  '<tr><td>5 points for Gryffindor</td></tr>' +
  '<tr><td>10 points for Hufflepuff</td></tr></table>';
  var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  GmailApp.sendEmail('user@me.com',subject, body,{from: alias[0], name:"The Tourney Committee",htmlBody: htmlBody});
  return;
}
```

The (obvious) problem I have is that the .mDayUpdate presents out as the literal string in the HTML email:

`<table><tr><th>Result</th><th>Points</th></tr><tr><td>5 points for Gryffindor</td></tr><tr><td>10 points for Hufflepuff</td></tr></table>`

Given it's an HTML email I can't user innerHTML or a js scriptlet in the HTML (I believe) and cannot find another way for the string to be recognised as HTML in the email and hence present as the 2 row list. The reason why I cannot just pass the 2 list items using separate lines/variables is because the email will be sent daily and each day it will have a dynamic list generated by js with a different number of items in it - some days could be 3 other days could be 10 etc. Have also tried HTML list etc. but naturally same problem persists as it's a string parse to HTML email challenge. All thoughts/help gratefully received.

Comment: I think that in your situation, it is required to know your HTML template of `daily-email`. So, can you provide it?

Comment: Thanks for coming back Tanake - haven't given you all the set-up...just the piece where I am trying to produce the list...let me know if you need more...
'<td>Team Results</td>
   </tr>
     <div>
        <?= mDayUpdate ?>
     </div>
    <tr>
   </td>'

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `'<td>Team Results</td> </tr> <div> <?= mDayUpdate ?> </div> <tr> </td>'`, in this case, please modify `<?= mDayUpdate ?>` to `<?!= mDayUpdate ?>` and test it again. I think that the reason for your current issue is due to this. So, I flagged it as a duplicate question.

Comment: Ooof - thanks Tanake as always. How did I miss that?(!)